# My API level in Unity is 0

Tags: android, unity-game-engine

I have installed android-sdk on my computer. My API level is 27 but when I want to build an android app in Unity I have an error that says The minimum API level you need is 23 but the android API level on my computer is 0.
I have uninstalled and reinstalled the android SDK. I changed the name of my android folder in the tools folder from android 8.0.1 to android_23 and android_27.

I changed the folder of android SDK.

I don't have android studio on my PC.

I don't know what to do. Help Please.
[image: sdk manager image]

Comment: post your android sdk manager image.

Comment: @moje_mast_ram i edited my post and uploaded the image there

Answer (score 0):

Remove SDK platform above then 23. Minimum(Maximum) install API should be 23. don't install SDK Platform greater then 23, You have APi 27, so uninstall it and install 23.

Comment: Your unity version has limitation like, You must have minimum sdk 23 otherwise it can't process. You don't install it.

Comment: I uninstalled and reinstalled android SDK and unity for several times. at last i used android studio to install android SDK. SDK was right in android studio but still didn't work in unity. but by using update API level button in unity at last my problem was solved. but because of my country i should use VPN.